# How to generate URL gallery sequence between two numbers?

Tags: javascript, url, sequence, gallery

I have a large number of galleries i'd like to download, and I know the names of the last image file in the sequence, but i'm not sure how i'd go about creating the series of image links to use with a download manager.

Currently I have the html links in a text file with the 1st and last image in brackets, i.e:

```
http://www.example.com/manufacturer/csg/img_[001-018].jpg
http://www.example.com/manufacturer/pae/img_[001-014].jpg 
http://www.example.com/manufacturer/lucid/img_[001-010].jpg
etc
```

Is there a way to generate all those links based on the numbers in the brackets without doing them one by one?

I found the below javascript elsewhere, but this can only generate the sequence from user input of the first and last image, my links can all vary.

```
var fso, f1;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
f1 = fso.CreateTextFile("URLs.txt", true);

var i,j;
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
f1.write ("http://www.example.com/gallery/img00" + i + ".jpg\n");
}
f1.close();
```